# Software like xclip that comes standard on just about all Linux Distros with X?

Tags: linux, clipboard, utilities

I have an application that needs to access the clipboard on *nix OSs but I do not have access to the X event loop because of how it works. Therefore I need to send a command to another application to perform copy paste of strings. I was going to use xclip until I found out it is not standard with every Linux distro. Is there an application that comes standard on every (or almost every) Linux distro that can do copy paste of strings?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty confident that your only other reasonable option is `xsel`, and that's not really any safer a bet than `xclip`.

If you're *really* desperate, check whether Vim or Emacs is compiled with X support, in which case you could automate them into handling it for you, but this is a longshot.